# Matlab DSP System Toolbox for complex algorithm design

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

So far I was prototyping in Matlab some signal processing algorithms for biomedical applications. It looks like a batch of .m functions for offline signal processing.

But as the complexity of algorithms increased, I realized that my functions should interact with each other in realtime mode. For example, func1 can detect different events/states and the further work of func2 depends on that events (and vice versa).

Then I found that using Matlab System objects with frame-based concept can help me with that: http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/gs/what-are-system-objects.html
"For simple, one-time computations use MATLAB functions. However, if you need to design and simulate a system with many components, use System objects."

But when I started to explore this tool, I have encountered some restrictions:
In many Matlab examples there are several standard Objects used within a single workflow with equal frame length (a sequence of several step(obj) methods inside a single loop). While in Simulink there are common schemes with standard built-in blocks.

What I need is connection of high-level custom Objects (=stages of algorithm), which can have different frame lengths, can be switched depending on a particular state of the system, and can share some events with each other.

I see two different ways:

1) Using simple main script with common variables, step(objects), and several branches, that describe whole system behavour and control management.

2) Using Simulink diagrams.

---

So, my questions are:

1) How can I handle different frame lengths? (E.g. one step() of 1k samples -> then 10 steps() of 100 samples -> then waiting data for a step() of 3k samples)

2) What are advantages of using Simulink, except graphical representation?

3) If using Simulink, where should I keep some common data/parameters and how can I switch workflow between different objects?

Comment: If you have lots of conditional branches, it is easier to code in MATLAB. Do you have different frame lengths for same data? System objects should be able to handle different frame lengths.

Comment: Yes, now I am writing and testing some tuned hand-written DSP objects. Also, I have found Stateflow library for handling finite-state machines (for different modes/events). For now I am trying to decide if I should write some low-level but tuned-up algorithms, which can be difficuilt to manage/debug, or use high-level instruments, which are more complex in use and can be partial matching my tasks.